# how do I specify in my pip requirements.txt to install from git repository

Tags: python, git, pip, requirements.txt

`pip` is able to install directly from git.

Example:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com:owner/repository_name.git
```

After developing a project in a virtual environment and installing all its dependencies, I construct the `requirements.txt` file using the shell command pip freeze > requirements.txt.

However, in the requirements.txt file, I get a package name and version number like this (random example):

```
Flask==0.10.1
```

This then breaks if I run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I would like to explicitly specify that the installation should happen from a particular git repository / branch.

I'm not sure how to do that. Currently, running `pip install -r requirements.txt` breaks at the package that is to be installed from git directly. So, when it breaks, I issue the install command manually, and run `pip install -r requirements.txt` again. This is bad for automation, and on-boarding new dev's to my project because the new guys have to ingest the hack as well as the project code. Ideally, I want to run the install command once.